# JAR no funciona con AbsoluteLayout

Tags: java-8, layout, netbeans-absolutelayout

Estoy trabajando con Netbeans 8.2 y versión de Java 8, al ejecutar mi programa desde el IDE de Netbeans corre sin problema pero desde linea de comando me lanza el siguiente error:

```
java -jar MiPrograma.jar

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout
```

En algunos foros recomiendan agregar al classpath la libreria de AbsoluyteLayout, la cual selecciono desde el siguiente path:

```
..\NetBeans 8.2\java\modules\ext\AbsoluteLayout.jar
```

Lo he hecho de esta manera pero me continua dando el mismo error, alguien puede ayudarme con este problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

me he encontrado con el mismo problema que tu, por eso he encontrado tu misma pregunta. Bien, lo he solucionado así.

1º pon el cursor encima de la libreria AbsoluteLayout en netbeans, en tu proyecto, te dirá la ruta donde se encuentra el .jar de esta libreria, ve a la ruta y copialo.

2º descomprime todo el archivo de TU .jar en una carpeta vacia, elimina el .jar original.

3º crea una carpeta lib (por ejemplo), si no la tienes, en la carpeta donde has descomprimido tu .jar.

4º modifica el meta-inf con un bloc de notas y añade este path 
Class-Path: lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar

5º selecciona tu programa y vuelve a comprimirlo, en zip por ejemplo y cambiale la extensión a .jar

6º vuelve a ejecutarlo!

source: 
https://programandoointentandolo.com/2013/04/crear-archivo-jar-en-netbeans-con-librerias-externas.html

Comment: Si me funciono! Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La solución es realmente sencilla. Descargan el archivo JAR de esta página (https://es.osdn.net/projects/sfnet_printman/downloads/dist/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar/) luego lo añaden como cualquier otro archivo comprimido, cabe mencionar que no es necesario descomprimir, y lo agregan en Add JAR/Folder y desaparece el error.

Esto básicamente se debe a que la librería con la que se está trabajando o está por defecto no soporta AbsoluyteLayout.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/195187)

Comment: Amigo buenas tardes... De antemano gracias por tu observación, no obstante creo que es simple lo que menciono arriba, lo único que necesitan hacer es descargar la librería de cualquier fuente e instalarlo,el link es sólo un medio para reducir el tiempo de búsqueda, pero al mismo tiempo es opcional. No es algo que demanda tanta complicación. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando Maven para el proyecto, **el pom.xml** debe contener la **dependencia del Absolute Layout** y el **pluggin para el jar con dependencias**.

```
<dependencies>
       ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
        <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE140</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.ejemplo.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```