# ¿Por qué no puedo ejecutar normalmente un proyecto de netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-absolutelayout

Estoy haciendo una ventana donde va a ir una menú en barra y debajo de ella existirá un panel de escritorio.  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los items en la barra ya están visualmente y en el código de la misma ventana

y esta es una de las sub ventanas (internal frames) que van a ser llamadas en los diferentes MenuItems; en cada una de estas ventanas no he puesto el código todavía (los botones no hacen algún método u operación) solamente estaría el enlace y cuando ejecuto para ir visualizando como está quedando el proyecto, solo puedo ver la ventana de administración y en el output del IDE obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1156)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(JLayeredPane.java:233)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JDesktopPane.addImpl(JDesktopPane.java:488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:440)
    at interfaces.SISconfig.usuariosActionPerformed(SISconfig.java:254)
    at interfaces.SISconfig$1.actionPerformed(SISconfig.java:76)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:374)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1028)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1072)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

el que haya puesto el frame y el pane como AbsoluteLayout no creo que incida con la Exception que se muestra ya que tampoco he agregado otra capa; talvez alguien sepa que tiene que ver este mensaje, ya que rehice el proyecto en otra máquina y me salía el mismo error.

Estoy utilizando el ApacheNetbeansIDE17

lo de la vGestUsuarios que es la siguiente en ser llamada en los items tiene:

```
import dao.DAOusuario;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import interfaces.SISconfig;
import static interfaces.SISconfig.pnlEscritorioP;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import modelo.Usuario;

public class vGestUsuarios extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
    Dimension tamEscritorioP, tamVent;
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    Usuario u = new Usuario();
    DAOusuario daoUsu = new DAOusuario();
    int index = -1;
    ArrayList<Usuario> lista;

    public vGestUsuarios() {
        initComponents();        
        String titulos[] = {"Estado", "Nombre", "Usuario"};
        dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(titulos);
                                                                       
        //refrescarUsuarios();       
        //llenarTareas();        
    }
    
//    public void borrar(){
//        txtUsuario.setText("");
//        txtContrasena.setText("");
//    }

    public void llenarUsuarios(JTable tabla) {
        ArrayList<Usuario> lista = daoUsu.read();
        Object[][] data = new Object[lista.size()][4];
        Object[] columnNames = {"Estado","Nombre","Usuario"};        
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            //data[i][0] = u.getId();
            if (u.getEstado() == 1) {
                
            }
            data[i][0] = u.getEstado();
            data[i][1] = u.getNombre();
            data[i][2] = u.getUsuario();
            lista.add(u);
        }
        tblUsuarios.setModel(dtm);
    }
    
    public void mostrarUsuarios() {
        tblUsuarios.setModel(new DefaultTableModel() {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 0) { // index of the selected column
                    return Boolean.class;
                } else {
                    return String.class;
                }
            }
        });
        tblUsuarios.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            private final JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                    checkBox.setSelected((Boolean) value);
                    checkBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    return checkBox;
                } else {
                    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                }
            }
        });
         ArrayList<Usuario> lista = daoUsu.read();
        
    }
    
    public void refrescarUsuarios(){
        while(dtm.getRowCount() > 0){
            dtm.removeRow(0);
        }
        lista = daoUsu.read();
        for(Usuario usuario : lista){
            Object columna[] = new Object[3];
            columna[0] = usuario.getEstado();
            columna[1] = usuario.getNombre();
            columna[2] = usuario.getUsuario();
            dtm.addRow(columna);
        }
        tblUsuarios.setModel(dtm);
    }
    
    public void llenarTareas() {        
        //tblTareas = new JTable(ModeloTablaTareas.model,columnModel);
    }   
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        pnlEscritorio = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        scrollUsuarios = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tblUsuarios = new javax.swing.JTable();
        scrollTareas = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        pnlTareas = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        chckT1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT2 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT3 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT4 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT5 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT6 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT7 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT8 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT9 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT10 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT11 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT12 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT13 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT14 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT15 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT16 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT17 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT18 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT19 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT20 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT21 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT22 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT23 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT24 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT25 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT26 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT27 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT28 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT29 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT30 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT31 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT32 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT33 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT34 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT35 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT36 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT37 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT38 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT39 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT40 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT41 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT42 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT43 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT44 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT45 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT46 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT47 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT48 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT49 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT50 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT51 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT52 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT53 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT54 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        chckT55 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        btnNuevo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnModificar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnContrasena = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setClosable(true);
        setIconifiable(true);
        setTitle("Usuarios");
        setAlignmentX(0.0F);
        setAlignmentY(0.0F);
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(702, 408));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(702, 408));

        pnlEscritorio.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 430));
        pnlEscritorio.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 430));

        tblUsuarios.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        tblUsuarios.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Activo", "Nombres", "Usuario"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, true, true
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        tblUsuarios.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
        tblUsuarios.setShowVerticalLines(true);
        tblUsuarios.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
        tblUsuarios.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        tblUsuarios.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                tblUsuariosMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        scrollUsuarios.setViewportView(tblUsuarios);
        if (tblUsuarios.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            tblUsuarios.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
            tblUsuarios.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(10);
            tblUsuarios.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
            tblUsuarios.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(145);
            tblUsuarios.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
            tblUsuarios.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(115);
        }

        pnlTareas.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        pnlTareas.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(251, 1800));
        pnlTareas.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        chckT1.setText("Modificar caja predeterminados");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 6, -1, -1));

        chckT2.setText("Acceso a opciones de configuración");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 26, -1, -1));

        chckT3.setText("Configuración de usuarios");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 46, -1, -1));

        chckT4.setText(".");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 66, -1, -1));

        chckT5.setText("..");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 86, -1, -1));

        chckT6.setText("Autoriza cambiar proveedor en presupuesto");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 106, -1, -1));

        chckT7.setText("Crear proveedores en medios");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 126, -1, -1));

        chckT8.setText("*Anular facturas / proformas");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 146, -1, -1));

        chckT9.setText("*Eliminar factura / proforma");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 166, -1, -1));

        chckT10.setText("Liberar factura anulada");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 186, -1, -1));

        chckT11.setText("Acceso a Balance General");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT11, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 206, -1, -1));

        chckT12.setText("Acceso a Balance de Comprobación");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT12, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 226, -1, -1));

        chckT13.setText("Acceso a Perdidas y Ganancias");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT13, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 246, -1, -1));

        chckT14.setText("Proceso de mayorización");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT14, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 266, -1, -1));

        chckT15.setText("Asiento de apertura");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT15, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 286, -1, -1));

        chckT16.setText("Cierre de periodo");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT16, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 306, -1, -1));

        chckT17.setText("Agregar cuentas a egreso");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT17, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 326, -1, -1));

        chckT18.setText("Modificar cuentas en egreso");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT18, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 346, -1, -1));

        chckT19.setText("Eliminar cuentas en egreso");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT19, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 366, -1, -1));

        chckT20.setText("Agregar cuentas a ingreso");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT20, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 386, -1, -1));

        chckT21.setText("Modificar cuentas en ingreso");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT21, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 406, -1, -1));

        chckT22.setText("Eliminar cuentas en ingreso");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT22, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 426, -1, -1));

        chckT23.setText("Uso de cuentas de clientes en ingresos");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT23, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 446, -1, -1));

        chckT24.setText("Uso de cuentas de banco en ingresos");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT24, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 466, -1, -1));

        chckT25.setText("Cierre mensual");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT25, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 486, -1, -1));

        chckT26.setText("Creación de cuentas");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT26, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 506, -1, -1));

        chckT27.setText("Modificar cuentas");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT27, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 526, -1, -1));

        chckT28.setText("Eliminar cuentas");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT28, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 546, -1, -1));

        chckT29.setText("Numeración de comprobantes");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT29, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 566, -1, -1));

        chckT30.setText("Uso de la cuenta bancos");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT30, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 586, -1, -1));

        chckT31.setText("Creación de diarios contables");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT31, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 606, -1, -1));

        chckT32.setText("Movimientos de debito (+) ingresos DEBE");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT32, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 626, -1, -1));

        chckT33.setText("Movimientos de credito (-) ingresos HABER");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT33, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 646, -1, -1));

        chckT34.setText("Modificar autonumerico de cheques (cuenta banco)");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT34, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 666, -1, -1));

        chckT35.setText("Modificar vencimientos clientes");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT35, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 686, -1, -1));

        chckT36.setText("Modificar porcentajes de gastos");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT36, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 706, -1, -1));

        chckT37.setText("Modificar códigos contables de proveedores internos");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT37, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 726, -1, -1));

        chckT38.setText("Modificar códigos contables de proveedores externos");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT38, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 746, -1, -1));

        chckT39.setText("Modificar códigos contables de medios publicitarios");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT39, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 766, -1, -1));

        chckT40.setText("Acceso a contribuyentes");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT40, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 786, -1, -1));

        chckT41.setText("Acceso a autorizaciones externas");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT41, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 806, -1, -1));

        chckT42.setText("Crear egresos");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT42, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 826, -1, -1));

        chckT43.setText("Crear facturas");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT43, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 846, -1, -1));

        chckT44.setText("Crear ingresos");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT44, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 866, -1, -1));

        chckT45.setText("Crear ND");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT45, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 886, -1, -1));

        chckT46.setText("Crear NC");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT46, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 906, -1, -1));

        chckT47.setText("Crear retenciones");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT47, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 926, -1, -1));

        chckT48.setText("Acceso a autorizaciones internas");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT48, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 946, -1, -1));

        chckT49.setText("Anular comprobantes contables");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT49, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 966, -1, -1));

        chckT50.setText("Anular retenciones");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT50, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 986, -1, -1));

        chckT51.setText("Eliminar retenciones");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT51, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 1006, -1, -1));

        chckT52.setText("Crear liquidaciones de compra");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT52, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 1026, -1, -1));

        chckT53.setText("Configurar cuentas de grupo");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT53, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 1046, -1, -1));

        chckT54.setText("Permiso para elegir establecimiento en procesos");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT54, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 1066, -1, -1));

        chckT55.setText("Revertir conciliaciones bancos");
        pnlTareas.add(chckT55, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(6, 1086, -1, -1));

        scrollTareas.setViewportView(pnlTareas);

        btnNuevo.setText("Nuevo");
        btnNuevo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnNuevoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnModificar.setText("Modificar");
        btnModificar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnModificarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnContrasena.setText("Contraseña");
        btnContrasena.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnContrasenaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout pnlEscritorioLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pnlEscritorio);
        pnlEscritorio.setLayout(pnlEscritorioLayout);
        pnlEscritorioLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            pnlEscritorioLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(pnlEscritorioLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(pnlEscritorioLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(scrollUsuarios, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 390, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(pnlEscritorioLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(btnNuevo)
                        .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                        .addComponent(btnModificar)
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                        .addComponent(btnContrasena)))
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addComponent(scrollTareas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 280, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        pnlEscritorioLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            pnlEscritorioLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(pnlEscritorioLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(pnlEscritorioLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(pnlEscritorioLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(scrollUsuarios, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 370, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                        .addGroup(pnlEscritorioLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(btnNuevo)
                            .addComponent(btnModificar)
                            .addComponent(btnContrasena)))
                    .addComponent(scrollTareas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 410, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(pnlEscritorio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(pnlEscritorio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void tblUsuariosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        //vnaCreaUsu
    }                                        

    private void btnNuevoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        vCreaUsuario vnaCreaUsu = new vCreaUsuario();
        pnlEscritorioP.add(vnaCreaUsu);        
        tamEscritorioP = pnlEscritorioP.getSize();
        tamVent = vnaCreaUsu.getSize();
        vnaCreaUsu.setLocation((tamEscritorioP.width - tamVent.width)/2, (tamEscritorioP.height - tamVent.height)/2);
        vnaCreaUsu.show();
    }                                        

    private void btnModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        
    }                                            

    private void btnContrasenaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        
    }                                                             
}
```

Comment: Sin el código completo no podemos saber que está pasando. Te recomiendo reemplazar el Absolute layout por alguno(s) de los layouts que si vienen por defecto en la librería  swing.

Comment: quieres ver las declaraciones que el mismo IDE realiza sobre cada objeto que se utiliza y ya intente cambiando de layout por alguna otra opción pero es el mismo chiste... trate de simplificar imágenes pero ya te voy a subir todo lo del código que tengo...

Comment: Hola Santiago, el problema esta en los layouts, si ves [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/278007/jar-no-funciona-con-absolutelayout) tal vez logres solucionarlo.

Comment: @SantiagoBarreiro te falta el codigo de vGestUsuarios que es el que marca error, opino que no es un Component